# 3d spatial string-net model and its plaquette term

Tags: mathematical-physics, topological-order, spin-models

Can someone explain the following sentence, saying the difference betweeen [the 2d string-net plaquette intersections and 3d string-net plaquette intersections](http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/strnet.pdf)?

> Thus, for 3d sting-net model, if
>   we shrink the segment I3I4 to a point, these **two plaquette boundaries
>   intersect exactly once — unlike neighboring plaquettes in the
>   honeycomb lattice, which intersect tangentially when their common
>   boundary is shrunk to a point**.

Kind of understand the statement, but not sure what the paper wants to emphasizes for "unlike neighboring plaquettes in the honeycomb lattice, which intersect tangentially when their common boundary is shrunk to a point."

Perhaps the emphasis is on the 3d string-net intersection boundary shrinks to a point needs not to be tangential?

[image]

Comment: Linking to the pdf of a paywalled article is about the worst thing you can do.  Can you link to the arxiv version (or, at least, to the abstract at PRB)?

Comment: Did it, free: https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/36810

Comment: This is Levin's PhD thesis!  And you are saying this has been published at PRB??

Comment: The paper you originally linked is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404617